# Save value in memory and get it

Tags: java, swing

I am working on swing application, the steps below explains my problem.

> 1. I have a dialog box where I need to select the College.
> 2. Once I select the department, that window will be closed with the "dispose();" method.
> 3. Then one more window will pop-up, where I have to select the department based on the selected college.

Now the issue is the object of the Collage class has been destroyed, as that pop-up has been closed, so how can I can store the selected collage value in memory in Java.

Code Example :

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Sample first = new Sample();
        first.setData(1);

        Sample second = new Sample();
        System.out.println(first.getData());  // 1
        System.out.println(second.getData()); // 0
    }

}


public class Sample
{
    private int number;

    public int getNumber()
    {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number)
    {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public void setData(int a)
    {
        setNumber(a);
    }

    public int getData()
    {
        return getNumber();
    }
}
```

I want value 1 using the second object, it should be like "second.getData()" should bring the value 1. is it possible if yes then how ?
Thanks.

Comment: Just before calling `dispose()` put the value in the variable where you need it to be.

Comment: @RealSkeptic : I have tried with getter/setter but when again I create object college class then that variable get re-initialized.

Comment: you can use JoptionPane.OpenInputDialog(...), for taking input and based upon user input you can use that value and do something in a background.

Comment: Please post minimum code sample

Comment: Then your problem is not with the closing of the window - it's with the way you handle your data. The variable should be declared somewhere that is available to the method that creates the college class instance, and it should probably be passed as a parameter to its constructor so that it's saved. But you really need to show some code for the classes you use.

Comment: @vishalgajera : edited question, need some more help.

Comment: @Harshil, see my EDITED Section for your second query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try somewhat likewise,

I have been represent idea , now you can lead ahead by your own requirement-wise,

```
public class InputSelect {

    public static final String[] colleges = { "College-1", "College-2", "College-3", "College-4" };

    public static final String[][] dept = {{"college-1 Department-1","college-1 Department-2"},{"college-2 Department-1","college-2 Department-2"},{"college-3 Department-1","college-3 Department-2"},{"college-4 Department-1","college-4 Department-2"}};

      public static void main(String[] args)
      {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Input Dialog Example 3");
        String favoritecollege = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, 
            "Select Your Choice Colleges : ",
            "Choose College",
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, 
            null, 
            colleges, 
            colleges[0]);

        int index = 0;

        for(String clg : colleges){
            if(favoritecollege.equals(clg)){
                break;
            }else{
                index++;
            }
        }

        String favouriteDept = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, 
                "Select Your Choice Department : ",
                "Choose Dept of "+ favoritecollege +" college : ",
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, 
                null, 
                dept[index], 
                dept[index][0]);

        System.out.printf("Favorite College is %s.\n", favoritecollege);
        System.out.printf("Favorite Dept is %s.\n", favouriteDept);


      }

}
```

**EDITED**

```
public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Sample first = new Sample();
        first.setData(1);
        //Either
        //Sample second = new Sample();
        //second.setData(1);
        //or 
        Sample second = first;

        System.out.println(first.getData());  // 1
        System.out.println(second.getData()); // here, you will get 1 after above changes made.
    }
```

You can do Either way,

Make sure if you choose this way,

```
Sample second = first;
```

then wherever you made changes Either on `first` or `second`. 
that should be reflect on both instance i.e. `first` and `second`.
because it's not 2-different instance. 
it's just one instance.

but if you choose this way,

```
Sample second = new Sample();
second.setData(1);
```

then it's different then `first`, means if you made any change on `second` then it should not **reflect** on `first`.

So, you can do whatever way, you are convenient .
Best of luck.

Comment: oh, now got the understanding, thnx vishal

Comment: @Harshil by the way, it's different question. so always try to post new question as a "new Question". you can not mix, i mean ask two different thing into one. like here. All the best